# Fire countdown from subclass

Tags: ios, objective-c, timer

I have those methods to create a simple countdown in my `ViewController.m`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    secondsLeft = 10;
}

- (void)updateCounter:(NSTimer *)theTimer {
    if(secondsLeft > 0 ){
        secondsLeft -- ;
        seconds = (secondsLeft %3600) % 60;
        myCounterLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d", seconds];
    }
    else{
        secondsLeft = 10;
    }
}

-(void)countdownTimer{
    secondsLeft = seconds = 0;
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f target:self selector:@selector(updateCounter:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
```

From where I call the method in the subClass :

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event { 
        [self.vc countdownTimer];
}
```

So I have a ViewController with a UIView inside. This UIView has a custom class. I want to call from this custom Class a method which is in the ViewController. I achieved to call it but the `myCounterLabel.text` is logged as `(null)`... Whereas I call the method from the ViewController itself the `myCounterLabel.text` is correctly logged with the left seconds. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you show the NSLog the messages?

Comment: I gave a shot with your code and its exactly working fine. The timer is being called repeatedly and logging seconds from 9 to 0.

Comment: Sorry what do you mean? I just added a NSLog at the first line of the countdownTimer to be sure that method is called.

Comment: @Mahi Do you think my problem could come that I'm calling the method from a subclass of an UIView which is use in my main ViewController ?

Comment: I think this might.  I tried calling it from another View Controller .Can you show your piece of code from where you are calling this vc's timer method.

Comment: @Mahi Added it in my original post.

Comment: is Otherclassm a container view controller of  ViewController.m ? have you added viewcontroller as child?

Comment: @Mahi @JavierFloresFont I investigated more in my code : So I have a ViewController with a UIView inside. This UIView has a custom class. I want to call from this custom Class a method which is in the ViewController. I achieved to call it but the `myCounterLabel.text` is logged as `(null)`... Whereas I call the method from the ViewController itself the  `myCounterLabel.text` is correctly logged with the left seconds. I hope it's clearer. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

countdownTimer method is in view controller.m file and you calling it from other view controller by making object of ViewController controller but do you notice one thing? When you call countdownTimer method then everytime secondsLeft will be 0 and it set to 10 so whenever you call countdown timer method secondsLeft will be reset.
So timer will not start

Comment: I don't see any condition for starting the timer based on the seconds value.

Comment: Thanks, I don't totally get what you said could you tell me what should I change ? btw, I don't call the method from another VC but I call from subclass of UIView.

Comment: Have you put breakpoints to check whether updateCounter is call or not?

Comment: @bhoomi It's called - Btw I just updated my post to clarify the context.